# How to count total time from start date and end date in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Our user schema like this ...

```
const docSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userType: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
            'customer',
            'driver'
        ]
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        refPath: 'userType'
    },
    device: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
            'Android',
            'IOS'
        ]
    },
    appVersion: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    deviceId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    connected: {
        type: Date,
        default: ''
    },
    disconnected: {
        type: Date,
        default: ''
    }
}, {
        timestamps: true
    });
```

Now, we have to count total online time of the user using connected and disconnected,
Anyone can help us how can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it seems that, for each session *( i.e. one connect and disconnect )* you are creating a document for the user in `DocSchema` [ Let, call the model `DocSchema` ]. And you want to know the total time of a user. You can use `aggregate`.

This is an example `aggregation` that finds the total time for the userId `searchKey`

```
Schema2.aggregate({
  $match: {
    userId: searchKey,
    $project: {
      diff: {
        $subtract: ['$disconnected', '$connected']
      }
    },
    $group: {
      _id: 'justAGroupName',
      total: {
        $sum: '$diff'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

For more, check [mongodb aggregation doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)